# How to target a <font> tag in an <a> tag and use hover effect?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am trying to redesign the look of the mobile menu on my Wordpress theme. I have most of the css done but I would like to have a `border-bottom` appear when you hover over the menu. I have tried to add this to the `<a>` tag but it underlines the whole div rather than just the text. Using the inspect tool, I see I need to target the `<font>` tag that is within the `<a>` tag but how do I apply the hover attribute to it?

Here is a basic example to explain the structure of the theme's menu.

```
<div id="menu-wrap">
    <ul id ="menu">
        <li class="menu-item>
            <a class="menu-link" href="www.website.com/link">
                <font style> Link Name </font>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't. `<font>` has been obsolete for many years. https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/obsolete.html#obsolete

Comment: This is just the way my Wordpress theme is structured. I'm not sure how to change it and, using the 'inspect' tool, targeting it is the only way I can get the effect I would like but I can only do so inline in the HTML using inspect. I just don't know how to do it outside of inspect.

Comment: Create a child theme of that parent theme and then edit that <font> tag out of the template. Or, simply style the <a> tags with css.

Answer (score 1):

The font element is <s>deprecated</s> **obsolete**. See more at MDN's site here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font

I would suggest using a `span` tag and targeting the span, e.g. `.menu-link:hover span`.

Comment: This is probably a really silly question, but how do I edit the HTML on my theme to use a `span` tag?

Comment: It's not deprecated anymore. It's obsolete! https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/obsolete.html#obsolete

Comment: Not that familiar with WordPress. While the `font` element is obsolete, it's not technically relevant to the crux of your question about CSS hover. Targeting `.menu-link:hover font` should work just the same for now.

Answer (score 0):

`a font:hover{}`

if there is only font tag in the a tag in that case u can use above format
or particular that font tag u can use `.menu-link font:hover{}`

Answer (score 0):

you can use :hover to create hover underline effect

```
<div id="menu-wrap">
    <ul id ="menu">
        <li class="menu-item">
            <a class="menu-link" href="www.website.com/link">
                <font style> Link Name </font>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<style>
    .menu-link{text-decoration:none;}
    .menu-link:hover{text-decoration:underline;}
</style>
```

Comment: I like the approach but it's still not targeting correctly. Nothing is happening for me unfortunately.

Comment: maybe in this way?

`<div id="menu-wrap">
    <ul id ="menu">
        <li class="menu-item">
            <a class="menu-link" href="www.website.com/link">
                 <font style> Link Name </font>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<style>
 a{text-decoration:none;}
    a:hover{text-decoration:underline;}
</style>`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `"` in your `menu-item` class, this could potentially break the render of the border.

For the font bottom border on hover, you can do this :

```css
.menu-link font:hover {
    border-bottom: aqua solid ;
}

// Or 

a font:hover {
    border-bottom: aqua solid ;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu-wrap">
    <ul id ="menu">
        <li class="menu-item">
            <a class="menu-link" href="www.website.com/link">
                <font style> Link Name </font>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Also, you should not use the `font` tag since it's [depreciated / not supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font) in HTML5.